# How to use environment variables for a docker image in AWS-ECR?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, docker, terraform, amazon-ecs

I made a docker image from a Spring-Boot-App, which has `application.properties` . One property for example is `user.name=xxx`. Now I uploaded the image to a AWS-ECR repository. Is there a way to inject this variable through a ECS-Task or maybe a other way ? For Deployment  I use Terraform.

Comment: You can pass environment variables to task definition. Here is the Cloudformation docs. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-taskdefinition-containerdefinitions.html. you should be able to do the same through terraform as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Boot allows you to [set configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) by a huge number of different ways:

> Spring Boot uses a very particular PropertySource order that is
>   designed to allow sensible overriding of values. Properties are
>   considered in the following order:
>
> 1. Devtools global settings properties on your home directory (~/.spring-boot-devtools.properties when devtools is active).
> 2. @TestPropertySource annotations on your tests.
> 3. @SpringBootTest#properties annotation attribute on your tests.
> 4. Command line arguments.
> 5. Properties from SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON (inline JSON embedded in an environment variable or system property)
> 6. ServletConfig init parameters.
> 7. ServletContext init parameters.
> 8. JNDI attributes from java:comp/env.
> 9. Java System properties (System.getProperties()).
> 10. OS environment variables.
> 11. A RandomValuePropertySource that only has properties in random.*.
> 12. Profile-specific application properties outside of your packaged jar (application-{profile}.properties and YAML variants)
> 13. Profile-specific application properties packaged inside your jar (application-{profile}.properties and YAML variants)
> 14. Application properties outside of your packaged jar (application.properties and YAML variants).
> 15. Application properties packaged inside your jar (application.properties and YAML variants).
> 16. @PropertySource annotations on your @Configuration classes.
> 17. Default properties (specified using SpringApplication.setDefaultProperties).

The simplest thing then is to set [environment variables for the ECS container definition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_ContainerDefinition.html#ECS-Type-ContainerDefinition-environment) so they get injected into the task at runtime. This will also override any properties set in `application.properties` due to the ordering of them.

A very basic example of the task definition in Terraform would look something like this:

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "example" {
  family                = "example"
  container_definitions = <<TASK_DEFINITION
[
    {
        "cpu": 10,
        "command": ["sleep", "10"],
        "entryPoint": ["/"],
        "environment": [
            {
                "name": "USER_NAME"
                "value": "xxx"
            }
        ],
        "essential": true,
        "image": "example",
        "memory": 128,
        "name": "example",
        "portMappings": [
            {
                "containerPort": 80,
                "hostPort": 8080
            }
        ]
    }
]
TASK_DEFINITION

}
```

Comment: In order to do that i have to call them into the dockerfile ?

Comment: Nope. It's the equivalent of running `docker run -e USER_NAME=xxx example:latest`

Comment: 2021, there is now an option to add name/value pair of environment variables directly while configuring the container on ecs